# How do I create a tally card for my items in my warehouse management system

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am building a warehouse management system and I want to design a tally card for each item in stock where store officers can receive and issue items in their warehouse and keep the transaction for each item. I want it to update the item balance in stock anytime the user receives and issued like a real-world tally card.

**I want it to look like this**
let's assume this is transactions made on item1.

|---Date ---|--- Desc---| Rec've |  Issue | Balance |

| 1-2-2023 | ---site1---  |   -------|  --76--| --235---|

| 3-2-2023 | --store1-- | --50--     |   ------ | ---285--   |

| 3-2-2023 | --store2-- | --15--     |   ------ | ---300--   |

On the Item list page, I want the user to click on a receive button and it will direct him to a form to enter the quantity he has received and the description and it will automatically update the balance and save that transaction against the item and the same applies to the issue.
And when the user clicked on the item, it will display all the transactions made on that item like the table above

So far, I have this in my model to save items and their info in the warehouse.

Model

```
class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True)
    part_No = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    balance_bd = models.IntegerField(default='0', null = True)
    warehouse = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    shelf_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    obsolete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```